# How to import class from user actionscript file

Tags: actionscript-3

I just want to create a class with two Numbers and a Bitmap. You can't have nested classes in a Timeline script so I figured I'd make .as file, namely "node.as". But I cannot for the life of me figure out how to import this class into the Timeline script so that I can use the class in my Timeline script.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to create a package to accomplish this.  The basic format is:

```
// folder specifies the relative folder of the package
package myfolder {

    // whatever other classes you need
    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.events.*;

    // base this on whatever class you need (in this case MovieClip)
    public class myclass extends MovieClip {

        private var myvariable: String;

        // constructor
        public function myclass() {
        }

        // functions only for use within the class
        private function myprivatefunction() {
        }

        // functions for use by the rest of the world
        public function mypublicfunction() {
        }
   }
}
```

The constructor is called when you create a new instance of the Class-- this is where you would do your initialization.  Then, in your timeline, just add something like:

```
import myclass;

var myclassinstance = new myclass();

myclassinstance.mypublicfunction();  // call a function in the class
```

See [adobe's help](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9e.html) for more details.

---

So I tried this:

```
package {
    import flash.display.*;

    public class Node {
        public var fX:Number;
        public var fY:Number;
        public var bmp:Bitmap;

        public function Node() { }
    }
}
```

And put it in a file called Node.as (note I needed to add the flash.display import, and the **capital "N" in the filename**).  In a FLA file in the same directory, I added this to the first frame script:

```
import Node;

var node = new Node();
trace("node="+node);
```

It compiled and ran without error.  There must be something else going on?  What version of Flash and of ActionScript are you using?

Comment: It isn't working for me. I have a simple node.as file in the same dir, so I have no package name. My node.as file looks like this:

    package {
        public class Node {
            public var fX:Number;
            public var fY:Number;
            public var bmp:Bitmap;

            public function Node() {
            }
        }
    }

Comment: And then in my timeline script I import Node. What is really blowing my mind is that if I just change the name of the class it alters the error. As Node I'm getting "Error #2136, SWF contains invalid data." The error occurs where I say node = new Node; But if I change all the references of Node to BmpNode in both the timeline script and node.as, and import BmpNode, it gives me the error "1172: Definition BmpNode could not be found." And the error occurs on the import BmpNode instead of at the call to new.